# Silverlight: Drag multiple rows from a datagrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, drag-and-drop

I am working on an app where the user needs to be able to drag items from a datagrid onto a button (this then fires some data updates). After some messing around, I have this working quite well. I have used the DataGridDragDropTarget controls from the toolkit for this.

I now need to allow the user drag multiple rows at once. While the datagrid allows me to select multiple rows, the DataGridDragDropTarget will only drag the first of the selections.

It looks like the DataGridDragDropTarget is not built for multiple dragging.

Would be grateful for any help on this one, this is the first time I have posted on SO - and hoping you guys can come through for me.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

It will drag multiple rows for sure. I am sure you are doing same mistake as i did. I believe all your code are fine.

To drag multiple row click on one row press shift or ctrl to select multiple but "Note here: If you release your mouse click here before drag it will forget what are the multiple items it has selected", so just drag without leaving mouse on your last selected item.(So, I think it works that way without doing anything)

However I am also searching for someway to make it work like drag and drop as in desktop. ;-)

Comment: Thanks webKite - if figured that out not long after posting here. It does work, but the need to hold down the ctrl/shift button will probably be an issue for my client.